# how to send an order placed email to seller in magento based on order status

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to send order placed email to seller only if the payment is success. I tried with below events.

> sales_order_place_after, sales_order_save_after, checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

and i am using below code to send email based on the order status like

```
if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING){
        $emailTemp = Mage::helper('marketplace')->getOrderPlaceNotifymailTemplate();

        $emailTempVariables = array();

        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getRealOrderId();
        $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $order['created_at'];
        $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $billinginfo;
        $emailTempVariables['myvar5'] = $payment;
        $emailTempVariables['myvar6'] = $shipping_info;
        $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shipping_des;
        $emailTempVariables['myvar8'] = $orderinfo;
        $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] = $Username;

        $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

        $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
        $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
        $emailTemp->send($useremail,$Username,$emailTempVariables);
      }
```

but i am not able to send emails,even i tried to send using

> if($order->getBaseTotalDue() == 0){
>   .......email code.........
>   }

if i removed if{} condition i can send email even if i cancel payment on payment gateway.I need to rectify this and i need to send emails only if payment is success.